# CDT: How can I analyze the AST of a c/c++ file which are not linked to some project in an Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

In my source code analysis Eclipse RCP project, I want to getAST to analyze the AST of some c/c++ files, which is neither a source file of a project within an eclipse workspace, nor a link resources of a project within an eclipse workspace. Basically, I do not have any workingspaces in my RCP application. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You need to programmatically create new project from folder of sources (make sure you have some basic .cproject file inside with correct source root):

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
project = workspace.getRoot().getProject("project");
if (!project.exists()) {
    IProjectDescription description = workspace.newProjectDescription("project");
    CCorePlugin.getDefault().createCDTProject(description, project, null);
} else {
    project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
}
```

After you can use AST:

```
ITranslationUnit translationUnit = (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(file);
IASTTranslationUnit ast = translationUnit.getAST();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way if you happen to have that file in the editor, then you can use getEditorInput method on the editor part to get ITranslationUnit, i.e.:

`// here is how you can get the active editor
 IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
 IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
 IEditorPart editorPart = window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor();`

`// for an external file the editor input will be of type ITranslationUnitEditorInput 
 IEditorInput input = editorPart.getEditorInput();
 if (input instanceof ITranslationUnitEditorInput) {
    ITranslationUnit externalTU = ((ITranslationUnitEditorInput) input).getTranslationUnit();
 }`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow aayupov. You must have a look at [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Actually here you are answering to a question which is asked 2 years ago. Although there is nothing wrong in it. :)